# Having problems with IPMI via SOL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tty, ipmi

SOL works as long as I have it set to 19200. As soon as I change it in grub and the bios to 115200, while the grub menu works and I get a message about loading kernel and ramdisk, all the boot text is garbage. I've tried forcing the ttys to 115200, but this does not change the results. This works correctly in ubuntu 12.04, but not in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out there are multiple locations that the bit rate has to be set
grub, for one, bios for a second, and in the ipmi controller itself for a third.
ipmitool sol set non-volatile-bit-rate 115.2 1 
ipmitool sol set volatile-bit-rate 115.2 1 
will change the third one, and then the whole boot process is visible and ipmi works properly.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set this up? I'm having trouble getting it setup properly in grub. Can you post a step by step by any chance? Thanks!